# How to sum array elements in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

im having a problem on my elements. how can i sum array elements like this?.

```
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[0][0]">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[0][1]">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[0][2]">

<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[1][3]">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[1][4]">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[1][5]">
```

and so on...

i want to sum all elements with first key is 0 and separate sum of elements with first key is 1.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: can you please more elaborate what you want exactly?

Comment: honestly I don't understand what you actually want!

Comment: i want to sum the values of these array elements grouped by the first key.. if the first key is 0 then the sum of noheadRecieved[0][0], noheadRecieved[0][1] and noheadRecieved[0][2] will be shown and so on

Comment: please check my answer where  i have sum values for all 0 and all 1 keys and store it in map. You can retrieve it anytime from map

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you can use map to store sum for 0,1, etc keys and retrieve it again as per your use.

```js
$(function(){
  var sumMap = {};
  
  $('input[name^="noheadRecieved"]').each(function(){
     var name = $(this).attr('name');
     var values = name.match(/\d/g);
     var existingVal = parseInt(sumMap[values[0]]) | 0;
     var newVal = existingVal + parseInt($(this).val());
     sumMap[values[0]] = newVal;     
  });
  alert(sumMap[0]);
  alert(sumMap[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[0][0]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[0][1]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[0][2]" value="3">

<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[1][3]" value="3">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[1][4]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[1][5]" value="3">
```

Comment: for example the sum of <input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[0][0]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[0][1]"  value="2">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[0][2]"  value="3"> the result is 6, then <input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[1][3]" value="3">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[1][4]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="noheadRecieved[1][5]" value="3"> the result is 7 how can i sum these array elements by group of first key dynamically?

Comment: please check my updated answer. run code snippet, you will get the sum  in alert.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=noheadRecieved]')).reduce(function(p, e) {
    var i = parseInt(e.name.split(/\D+/)[1]);
    return p[i] = (p[i] || 0) + parseFloat(e.value), p;
}, []);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sums = [];

for(var i = 0; i < noheadRecieved.length; i++)
{
    sum[i] = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < noheadRecieved[i].length; j++)
        sums[i] += noheadRecieved[i][j];
}
```

You can then access the sum of all elements where the first key is 0 by using sum[0].

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think below sample code may solve your issue.

```
var results = []; 
var addValue = function (index, value){
    var val = results[index];
    if(val && val != ""){
        results[index] += value;
    }else{
        results[index] = value;
    }
};

$("input[name^='noheadRecieved']").each(function(index, object){
    var index = parseInt($(object).attr("name").split(/\D+/)[1]);
    addValue(index, parseInt($(object).val()));
});

alert(" Key 0's sum = "+results[0]+" Key 1's sum = "+results[1]);
```

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/eshugoel24/zbzj5o9a/)

Please let me know if you will face any issue.